# How do I access a controller from a command in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, architecture, controller

I have a cron command that runs eveyr minute, checking the status of a Livestream webcast by using their Channel API. It simply pulls back whether the channel is live or not and the number of viewers. Depending on certain conditions (such as when the webcast is live), I want it to connect to a method in one of my controllers which will then `create` a new model instance and insert it into my database.

For example, here's the `fire()` method of my `WebcastCheckCommand`:

```
public function fire()
{
    $checker = new WebcastChecker();
    $checker->check();
}
```

Where my class `WebcastChecker` looks like this:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

class WebcastChecker {
    private $url = 'http://achannel.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.json';

    public function check() {
        $livestream = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->url));

        // Add to Database if livestream is active
        if ($livestream->channel->isLive === true) {
            // SOME CODE HERE TO GO TO A `CREATE` METHOD ON MY WEBCASTCONTROLLER    
        }
    }
}
```

I already have a `webcastStatusController`, but right now I am unsure of how to hook in to my `create` method, since this request is non-traditional in the sense that it doesn't use a view or routing to a particular URL.

```
class WebcastStatusController extends BaseController {
    // Via Cron
    public method create($channelInfo) {
        // Add to db here, update Redis keys 
    }

    // AJAX POST 
    public method getStatus() {
    }
}
```

How would I go about accessing my controller from `WebcastChecker`? Or am I doing this all wrong? It's my understanding Controllers should pass around information, so this seems like the right way to approach this. Or should I be using a different coding/architectural style to go about this task?

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking to do is save a record in the database I would suggest using a model here. Then you can include your model directly in your command and use Eloquent to create the record. Something like this:

```
class WebcastStatus extends Model {

  protected $table = nameOfTable;

}
```

And then in your command:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use path\to\models\WebcastStatus;

class WebcastChecker {
  private $url = 'http://achannel.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.json';

  public function check() {
    $livestream = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->url));

    // Add to Database if livestream is active
    if ($livestream->channel->isLive === true) {
        // http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete

        WebcastStatus::firstOrCreate($parameters);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Question: If you wanted to keep the method in a controller (instead of a model), how would you access it from a command? Reason I ask is perhaps the base controller has a method shared across other controllers extending it. Would the command be able to access this method also?